# How to get the db updated at timestamp value form custom table in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php

I have to get the updated at value from db custom table. But if I print the value it is showing before 5 30 hrs. How to get the value in phtml file without using dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Showing the result of  5.30 hr ago because of cache.

There this issue can resolve by two way

- One make your block cache false.
- The second resolution changes the cache time of  that block from
  which  phtml render

`const CACHE_TAG = 'my_cache_tag';
 protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    /* make Cache lifetime 10min */
        $this->addData(
            ['cache_lifetime' => 600, 'cache_tags' => [CACHE_TAG]]
        );
    }`

 On block , i have change cache life time to 10mins.
You have changes `cache_life_time`  by changing cache time at `_construct()`

Comment: need to show the updated time using core php getting wrong

Comment: have u disable the cache and check the php core give proper time or not>

Comment: yes i have disabled the cache and check it is not working

Comment: Please share your code  what you have tried